# TiledMap not rendering

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, tiled

I am trying to render an OrthogonalTiledMap I created using the map editor Tiled however for some reason nothing is showing up in my game screen; all I get is a black image being shown. I am using the Libgdx framework which has features for exactly these kinds of maps already built in however they won't work for me.

Libdgx also provides an example of rendering OrthogonalTiledMaps however it is outdated but I adjusted it to current Libdgx version but as already stated it doesn't work.

There are no errors nor exceptions being thrown. The .tmx file does also not contain any errors. All the used tileset are present and do not cause any errors.

This is my code:
`

```
public class My_Game extends ApplicationAdapter {
private TiledMap map;
private TiledMapRenderer renderer;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private CameraInputController cameraController;

@Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, w/8f, h/8f);
    camera.update();


    cameraController = new CameraInputController(camera);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(cameraController);

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("map.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1f / 8f);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    camera.update();
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
}
@Override
public void dispose () {
    map.dispose();
}
}`
```

Comment: Sometimes this happens because the map is too big, try with a small one

Answer (score 0):

Was a while since I did Libgdx so I might be thinking of something else, but don't you have to do some clearing in the render() function?
Try adding:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

as the first three lines there and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Nope did nothing but change the color from black to red.

Comment: Ok, then remove the middle line and do setToOrtho(false,...);
That's all I could think of. Otherwise I suspect something might be wrong with your textures.